# How can I make a single notification read and show it?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a list of database notifications, rendered like:

### Code

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-   toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre><i class="fas fa-bell"
            style="color:cornsilk"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                @foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                    href="/predmeti/{{$notification->data['subject_id']}}/obavjestenja/{{$notification->data['obavjestenje_id']}}"
                    style="color: #d66e0a">{{$notification->data['naslov']}}</a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                @foreach ($user->readNotifications as $notification)
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#">{{$notification->data['naslov']}}</a>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
```

#### Problem

Now what I want is when I click on a single notification, I want to be redirected to that notification(I have a blade file for that and it works).
And I also want to mark it as read in a database table plus change the color of it according to the status of a notification.
I tried it in a `Controller` but I can't seem to redirect to the following url :

```
    /predmeti/{{$notification->data['subject_id']}}/obavjestenja/{{$notification->data['obavjestenje_id']}}
```

From within the `Controller`. Do I need jquery for this or can it be done with route/controller?

Comment: so when you click on a notification the user will be redirected to another page (sort of dedicated page of the notification)?

Comment: Yes. For example like stackoverflow. I click it and I'm redirected to it but it's also marked as read.

Comment: Have you defined route for ```/predmeti/{{$notification->data['subject_id']}}/obavjestenja/{{$notification->data['obavjestenje_id']}}``` ?

Comment: you can do it directly in your "show" function defined in your controller. When you access the link `/predmeti/{{$notification->data['subject_id']}}/obavjestenja/{{$notification->data['obavjestenje_id']}}` i guess you have something in your controllers that allows you to render the page isn't it? In that controller you can also trigger an update to the notification itself and turn it to read 

or 

you can do an ajax call on your notification click just to update its status, honestly if you have to access your notification's page to set it read i suggest the first solution i wrote above.

Comment: I have a function that returns show for that specific 'obavjestenje'. But how can I can I pass $notification there so I can mark it as read?

Comment: can you attach that code which returns the show for a given notification? I guess it should be your controller. The ActionController linked to this path `/predmeti/{{$notification->data['subject_id']}}/obavjestenja/{{$notification->data['obavjestenje_id']}}`

Comment: `public function show($subject_id, $obavjestenje_id)
    {
        $obavjestenje=Obavjestenje::find($obavjestenje_id);
        return view('obavjestenja.show', compact('obavjestenje'));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have laravel on my machine at the moment but you could do something like:

```
public function show($subject_id, $obavjestenje_id) { 
   $obavjestenje=Obavjestenje::find($obavjestenje_id); 
   $notification = Notification::where('subject_id', $subject_id)
                   ->where('obavjestenje_id',  $obavjestenje_id)
                   ->update(['read_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp]);
   return view('obavjestenja.show', compact('obavjestenje'));
}
```

of course, if notification are also linked with the user (if they have a user_id) i suggest you to add also the user id in the where condition in order to update the correct record in your DB.

It's not tested so i'm not sure if syntax is fully correct but it should give you some solutions. hope it helps

Comment: There's an error with the update 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update() must be of the type array, string given'. I guess because the 'read_at' is a timestamp field. Also I tried using markAsRead but it says it's undefined even thoigh I put `use App\Notification;`.

Comment: I suppose you use carbon to generate timestamps, sorry i forgot that the update needs an array to be executed. try with ->update(['read_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp]);

Comment: I now get this error 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subject_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `notifications` set `0` = read_at, `1` = 1568370188, `notifications`.`updated_at` = 2019-09-13 10:23:08 where `subject_id` = 3 and `obavjestenje_id` = 18)'. Can it be because subject_id and obavjestenje_id are actually in data column in notifications which is json?

Comment: so you have a table Notifications which every record is just a json that contains stuff?

Comment: ` Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });` This is the table. And in data column is where I store json of all the information I need, like subject_id and obavjestenje_id. And read_at is supposed to work with markAsRead function but it doesn't for me.

Comment: yes, that's why can't be updated using subject_id and obavjestenje_id, you have to retrieve the notification and update its field. At this point i suggest you to use ajax calls, instead to read the json content in your records.

In your view you are already accessing your notification with the loop, isn't it? Ok, so you just need to attach an event on click and trigger an ajax call passing its $notification id. Then you should create a controller where you retrieve and update it by its ID

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I'll try even though I'm not that good with ajax. :D